# how to correctly flag (or vote to close?) the "please-give-me-the-code" questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, asking-questions, moderation

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415539/php-email-contact-form-with-dropdown-box-for-different-email-addresses), and something tells me it should be closed (flagged), cause he's asking to code for him.

But i'm not really sure if it this type of questions should be closed as **not constructive** or **not a real question**, or maybe there should be a new type of flag.. i'd call it the "he's making people work for free" flag

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this question! Downvoting and burnination ring - activate.

Comment: It's a terrible,  lazy question,  but I don't think this is a case for mod-flagging. Voting and closevoting should be enough to deal with it.
However, let's wait for what the mods say

Comment: =P hmm i had no idea that there was a difference between "flagging" and "voting for closing"... i've learned something new today

Comment: You voted to close, so flags don't even enter the picture.

Comment: NARQ on him[.](http://damnit)

Comment: Also see [What is the best Triage response for give me teh codez questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320536/608639) on Meta.SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should vote to close that question as "Not a real question", and in edge cases flag it with "other" reason "Not a real question"

Comment: *"Not a real question"* is no longer a close reason. Or at least not on Stack Overflow. Any thoughts on what to use in 2018?