# How to close "debug my program" or "give me the code" questions with new close types?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Before, I would close "debug my program" or "give me the code" questions as too localized.

How are they closed with new close types?

---

I have seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106147/how-to-correctly-flag-or-vote-to-close-the-please-give-me-the-code-question) and similar questions, but they are for old close vote types.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17506627/476681) is a typical example of "debug my code" question. The link shows whole code, but I doubt that question would help anyone in the future. Before, I would close it as too localized. How about now?

Comment: Also see [What is the best Triage response for give me teh codez questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320536/608639) on Meta.SO.

Answer (score 5):

Both fall perfectly well under:

> Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: hmmm which closing reason is that?

Comment: Its under off topic because...

Comment: @RichardTingle [Upvote this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186024/can-we-rename-the-off-topic-close-reason-label-on-the-primary-screen)

Comment: This is what I've been using, especially for typo questions. "I don't know how to type/spell" does not constitute any sort of understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: @animuson: I think true typo questions are a separate breed from these. Personally, I've been making a custom reason, something like "Once/now that this question is answered, it won't be/isn't appropriate for SO because its solution has no utility for future readers." Although [I am quite keen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167369/) on closing and deleting typo questions afterwards, I don't see anything particularly wrong with asking them. We all go code-blind from time to time.